# is_object always returns false in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

I'm using the php Session based Webforce cart. The following code works ok in IE and Firefox, but does not work in Chrome or Safari (i.e. WebKit).

```
include_once "../class/wfcart.php";

session_start();

$cart =& $_SESSION['wfcart'];  // point $cart to session cart.
if(!is_object($cart))          // is_object always returns false in Chrome... why?
    $cart = new wfCart();      // if it isn't an object, make a new cart
```

So the problem is Chrome is always creating a new cart because is_object returns false. So there is no way to enter more than one product in the Shopping Cart.

Do I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: PHP code has nothing to do with Chrome. It's possible that you have some Javascript code that doesn't work on Chrome, so it doesn't make some AJAX request it's supposed to, and your cart is not created as a result. Open Chrome's developer tools and look at the console.

Comment: new version of chrome, sometimes nulled session, or when you haven't favicon cgrome reset session too, so, try this in othe browser and tell us if work

Comment: I know Php is server side, that's the reason I cannot understand why is not working in Chrome, just makes no sense to me. is_object always returns false on Chrome, but it works perfect on Firefox and IE...

Comment: Dawid, I don't know what are you talking about... favicon???

Answer (score 0):

Session data is all stored server-side, and all the client gets is a session cookie.  Is your Chrome rejecting the cookie for some reason?  Or perhaps there is a subtle cookie domain issue that is tripping up Chrome?

Comment: No, My conf is Allow local data to be set. I have no restictions. This is driving me crazy.